# Are questions about the decisions to limit a feature on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

A Lenovo staff says that the bluetooth keyboards of the Yoga model are only compatible with the same model, not with other devices. Therefore my other computer cannot detect it. I want to know why this limitation happens. Does that a good question?

According to [What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center - Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), questions about "issues specific to corporate IT support and networks" are off-topic. But I guess one can easily generalize this question to any corporate? Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: I would avoid "why did a company or person do this?" as that would be off topic as it has nothing to do with computers. Instead focus on the actual problem with the hardware and your computer situation and preferably what you have tried and how you might fix or at least diagnose it. People bad, computers good.

Comment: How about asking "what would be the cons for allowing the keyboard to pair with other computers?"? Is it better?

Comment: Asking for pros and cons is edging across into opinion based as it depends on who you are. One person's pro is another person's con. I'd be suspecting that what they have done is not actually use Bluetooth, after all if it were a genuine Bluetooth keyboard then it would be usable with other devices, and there are plenty of proprietary wireless transceivers for keyboards and headsets and mice that need "pairing" but dont use Bluetooth. Ask about "how to do..." and what is preventing that rather than "why would someone...." Avoid people, focus on making the computer *do* something.

Comment: Your alternate question would just generate answers that stated user's opinion.  The real explanation is likely that talked to a low level support personal who was reading off a script that indicate A) what they said B) no actual explanation.  The real reason the keyboard wouldn't work is if it was BT, one computer had a BT receiver while the other one didn't. As long as you have a compatible BT receiver the keyboard would work. Most wireless keyboards are paired to a specific receiver, sometimes they are key, that prevents the use of a different receiver even from the same make and model.

Comment: @Mokubai hmm, had this question been asked in here, would it have been on-topic? [What is the advantage of traditional hosting over cloud hosting?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/128767/52079) I guess if it's well received in Webmasters, then it should be well received in here, right?

Comment: @Ooker the sites have different scopes and communities and some of the other sites are more lax in allowing vague opinion based questions. Just because one site allows it doesn't mean we have to. We are not Webmasters.

Comment: @Mokubai I see. So it seems that this site has a history of getting frustrations with questions about the decision of companies? Is there any previous discussion about this?

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for your input. I quote a part of your comment in the question now. Hope it's fine [A bluetooth keyboard can only work with a kind of computer. How to make it work with other computers?](https://superuser.com/q/1700143/301042)

Comment: @Ooker - We can’t explain why a company does something unless they have express those reasons. Very few companies have developers provide public remarks which results in the majority of “why did … do ..” questions being closed. It’s unnecessary to quote my comment

Comment: @Ramhound why is it unnecessary to quote your comment? I didn't paraphrase it. I understand that you cannot speak for them, but then someone working for them can help answer it? And if you cannot speak for them, then I guess you cannot be for sure that they are lying, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well - Its more "How do I get around restrictions my employer has put in place" with regards to corporate IT support. That said, as opposed to "why?" - not being able to pair a keyboard is *strange*, as is locking it down to a specific model. And well, tech support sometimes does lie.

A better question would be to start that you want to pair your keyboard (with details) with another machine, that you can't, and lenovo said that its compatible with specific devices only - then ask if you can do it anyway I think

Comment: I have asked the question here: [A bluetooth keyboard can only work with a kind of computer. How to make it work with other computers?](https://superuser.com/q/1700143/301042)